# Without changing code, how to force httpClient to use proxy by environment variables or JVM arguments

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I found these system settings `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` are of no use to httpClient. How to force the httpClient to use proxy by environment variables or VM arguments or something like those without changing code?

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this question? I am facing the same issue, a third party library (azure-keyvault-java-sdk) uses its own httpClient and I am unable to force it to use a proxy. The actual http calls are made in new Executor threads which does not allow me to set the ProxySelector in the calling thread as well. Any solutions?

Comment: We have the same issue, we want to do this without a code change where even a configuration change is considered a code change since we need to issue a new deployment to do so. Our conclusion is that it is not possible to override the client's configuration with JVM command line options, you just have to make a change to the client's configuration and issue a new release.

Answer (score 22):

in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1128

SystemDefaultHttpClient was added to ver. 4.2

see http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultHttpClient.html

Comment: As @wangf noted below, you can also use `.useSystemProperties()` before calling `.build()` on any HttpClientBuilder to read system properties such as `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#useSystemProperties()

Answer (score 22):

HTTP client (v 4.5.1 for my case) can use system proxy like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
//or 
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createSystem();
```

Comment: Exactly, you can use the system properties like this. Do not forget that for connection to https://... urls you have to use https.proxyHost etc properties.
A similar issue with details answer from my side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630330/what-java-properties-to-pass-to-a-java-app-to-authenticate-with-a-http-proxy/

Answer (score 6):

you can force proxy to `HttpClient` by yourself with `client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(host, port)` method. I usually create wrapper class around `HttpClient` and when initializing this class I setup proxy from whatever source (env. variables ...).

I used `java.net.ProxySelector.setDefault(new MyProxySelector())` in situation where you can't set proxy directly on `HttpClient`. You have to implement your own ProxySelector class and method select makes proxy selection based on requested URI. You can make url->proxy mapping to configure particular URI address to required proxy or return one proxy for all requested URI globally.

As I can see in HttpClient source code, there's no other way how to configure proxy only setProxy method. I'm using commons-httpclient-3.1.

Comment: @user496949 Can you create wrapper class around `HttpClient` and initialize it always by your way?

Comment: say, I have a 3rd party library, it uses httpclient inside to get something. How to dela with this situation?

Comment: In this case I used `java.net.ProxySelector.setDefault(new MyProxySelector());`. You have to implement your own ProxySelector class and method select makes proxy selection based on requested URI (Make url<->proxy mapping to configure particular URL address to required proxy ). As I can see in `HttpClient` source code, there's no other way how to configure proxy even setProxy method. I'm using commons-httpclient-3.1.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't manage this without code changes but you can get closer to native behaviour by using your own connection manager. See [ProxySelector changes URL's scheme from https:// to socket://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413552/proxyselector-changes-urls-scheme-from-https-to-socket/14563544#14563544)

Answer (score -17):

Does this help?

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxy_host);
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxy_host);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxy_port);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxy_port);
```

Or ofcourse you can pass the same properties via the commandline

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for httpclient, this is my question

Comment: The question clearly states that those variables were not working.