# ProxySelector changes URL's scheme from https:// to socket://

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy

I need to access Facebook but all outgoing communication is blocked on our server so I have to use proxy.

I initialize proxies with:

```
ProxySelector.setDefault(new ConfigurableProxySelector(mapping));
```

Proxy type is HTTP, proxy host and port are working (confirmed by simple wget test).

I'm trying to do this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("https://graph.facebook.com:443");

int status = httpClient.executeMethod(method);
```

Now, in my class ConfigurableProxySelector I have select method on which I have breakpoint:

```
public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
...
}
```

So, using HttpClient I make an request, which should be proxied and code stops at breakpoint in select() method in ConfigurableProxySelector.

But what is strange is that uri.scheme = "socket" and .toString() gives "socket://graph.facebook.com:443" instead of "https://graph.facebook.com:443".

Because ProxySelector have mapping for "https://" and not for "socket://", it does not find it and it ends with "Connection refused". What is strange is that select() method is called 4 times before execution ends with "Connection refused".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not solve this but I don't care anymore, our client decided to drop Facebook support ...

Comment: I am having the same problem right now. My guess is that the Apache HttpClient for some reason uses a different way to open the connection instead of a plain url.openConnection().

Answer (score 4):

Apache HTTP Client 3.1 will not natively honor HTTP Proxies returned from the default ProxySelector or user implementations.

### Quick Summary of ProxySelector

ProxySelector is a service class which selects and returns a suitable Proxy for a given URL based on its scheme. For example, a request for `http://somehost` will try to provide an HTTP proxy if one is defined. The default ProxySelector can be configured at runtime using System Properties, such as `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`.

### HTTPUrlConnection

An instance of HTTPUrlConnection will check against the default ProxySelector multiple times: 1st to select for `http` or `https`, then later when it builds the raw tcp socket, using the `socket` scheme. A SOCKS proxy could be used to proxy a raw tcp socket but are not often found in corporate environments, so a raw tcp socket will usually receive no proxy.

### HTTP Client 3.1

HC 3.1, on the other hand, will **never check the default ProxySelector for the `http`/`https` schemes**. It will check, however, at a later points for the `socket` scheme when it eventually builds the raw socket - This is the request you are seeing. This means the System Properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` are ineffective. This is obviously not ideal for most people who only have an HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

To work around this, you have two options: define a proxy on each HC 3.1 connection or implement your own HC 3.1 HTTPConnectionManager.

#### HTTPConnectionManager

The HTTPConnectionManager is responsible for building connections for the HC 3.1 client.

The default HC 3.1 HTTPConnectionManager can be extended so that it looks for a suitable proxy from a ProxySelector (default or custom) when building the request in the same way HTTPUrlConnection does:

```
public class MyHTTPConnectionManager extends SimpleHttpConnectionManager {
@Override
public HttpConnection getConnectionWithTimeout(
        HostConfiguration hostConfiguration, long timeout) {
    HttpConnection hc = super.getConnectionWithTimeout(hostConfiguration, timeout);

    try {
        URI uri = new URI( hostConfiguration.getHostURL());
        List<Proxy> hostProxies =  ProxySelector.getDefault().select(uri);
        Proxy Proxy = hostProxies.get(0);

        InetSocketAddress sa = (InetSocketAddress) Proxy.address();
        hc.setProxyHost(sa.getHostName());
        hc.setProxyPort(sa.getPort());

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        return hc;
    }   
    return hc;
}
}
```

Then, when you create an HC 3.1 client, use your new connection manager:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new MyHTTPConnectionManager() );
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work anymore, would you have any update on this problem?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I'm using the HttpComponents version 4.3.1 and I'm having the exact problem of the guy above regarding the proxy and socket thing.

I tried to use your code but SimpleHttpConnectionManager is not existing again. So does HostConfiguration. Also InetSocketAddress from java.net does not have setProxyHost and setProxyPort method.

So I was wondering if another work-around was introduced in HttpComponents since 3.1 version or do I need to use your code in a modified way.. 
Thanks

Comment: It looks like HC 4 is a totally different beast. It's probably best that you ask a new question for HttpComponents 4.3.x, perhaps linking to this question for further context.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the ProxySelector that changes the scheme, but the SocketFactory opening a Socket.
If the SocketFactory is null a SOCKS socket will be created by default which only allows SOCKS proxies. I don't know anything about Sockets and cannot tell you if there's a way to make it work with HTTP proxies.

But using another approach may help, since Apache HttpClient seems to have its own way to configure proxies.

```
client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);

if (proxyUser != null) {
    client.getState().setProxyCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort), 
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUser, proxyPassword));
}
```