# HTTPBuilder ignoring JVM proxy parameter

Tags: grails, groovy, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpbuilder

I need to go through a proxy to get to my target server. It seems that I can do it with code like this:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://www.somesite.com')
http.setProxy('proxy.com', 8080, 'http')
```

but not like this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://www.somesite.com')
```

Shouldn't this work?

---

The real problem is that I'm using `HTTPBuilder` from within a Grails application and was expecting that starting Tomcat using `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort` would let `HTTPBuilder` go through the proxy... but it is like `HTTPBuilder` is ignoring those JVM parameters.

---

It looks like the `httpclient` can be configured to use the JVM parameters like this: `client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(host, port)` (from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165126/without-changing-code-how-to-force-httpclient-to-use-proxy-by-enviroment-variab)). Can this be done in `HTTPBuilder` (I don't know how to reference the underlaying `httpclient`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also externalize the proxy params to Config.groovy, then set your proxy info via config.

Some examples of how to externalize configurations:

http://phatness.com/2010/03/how-to-externalize-your-grails-configuration/
http://www.comitservices.com/wp/?p=133

Then just grab your proxy info from config

```
def SomeService {
  def grailsApplication

  ..
    def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://www.somesite.com')
    http.setProxy(
      grailsApplication.config.proxyHost, 
      grailsApplication.config.proxyPort,
      grailsApplication.config.proxyScheme
    )
}
```

Comment: I know that I can do that, I was wondering why do I have to do that (why don't `-Dhttp.*` parameters work).

Comment: What about proxy authentification via username and password?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, in context to Grails applications, we can provide the host and port for Tomcat itself but cannot define the behavior of how HTTP calls has to go through proxies during Server startup.

You would need [add-proxy](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html) and [set-proxy](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html) settings for your app to connect to `somesite.com` over the proxy, `proxy.com`. For example:

```
grails add-proxy client --host=proxy.com --port=8080 
       --username=guest --password=guest
grails set-proxy client
```

It is not tested by you can also follow [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Solution-to-Grails-Proxy-Issue-for-installing-plugins-on-windows-td2994191.html) to see if you can use `System.setProperty`.

Comment: That's fine for `run-app`, but I'm taking about a Grails app deployed to Tomcat.

Comment: Then I think Level 3 in the [link](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Solution-to-Grails-Proxy-Issue-for-installing-plugins-on-windows-td2994191.html) provided in the answer is fit for your case.