# What Java properties to pass to a Java app to authenticate with a http proxy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, bamboo, http-proxy, apache-httpcomponents

I have a Java application that is trying to access a web service via http proxy. The Java app is 3rd party app for which we don't have access to source code.

Its launch can be configured by passing Java launch parameters among other things.
I am wondering what are the java properties that one can pass so that the app can use the logged in user's NTLM credentials to authenticate proxy connections?

When I passed https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort (i.e. -Dhttps.proxyHost=abcd ... to jvm command line), I do see difference in the logs. Now it fails with message below.

```
[WrapperSimpleAppMain] [AuthChallengeProcessor] ntlm authentication scheme selected 
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2015/06/03 14:49:25 | 2015-06-03 14:49:25,380 
INFO [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [HttpMethodDirector] No credentials available for NTLM <any realm>@proxy.ins.dell.com:80 
INFO  | jvm 5    | 2015/06/03 14:49:25 | Exiting due to fatal exception. 
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2015/06/03 14:49:25 | com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.RemoteAgentHttpException: HTTP status code 407 received in response to fingerprint request
```

I tried passing http.proxyUser and http.proxyPassword. That didn't work.
I am wondering what the right configuration is to make a Java app transparently use proxy info without having to make code changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I figured out by trial and error. Passing java.net.useSystemProxies=true along with https.proxyPort, https.proxyHost resolved this.

Basically the java vm command line got

**-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyserver.mycompany.com**

I didn't have to pass https.proxyUser, https.proxyPassword. I believe proxy authentication used the same credentials as my login NTLM credentials.

Comment: Using only `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` was sufficient for me. The proxy's host and port where read from the enviroment.

Comment: ADDITIONALLY: Keep an eye on changes done between jdk 1.8.0_025 and jdk 1.8.0_144! If your proxy uses basic authentication it seems as if you have to set the property `jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes` to an empty string - or remove "basic" from it! The jdk default is to NOT USE basic authentication here! Just add something like `-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""` as a jvm-option to allow (all) authentication types.

Answer (score 3):

One also needs to specify NT domain for NTLM authnetication to work.

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=MyDomain/username
```

or by setting

```
-Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=MyDomain
```

And you also MUST explicitly instruct HttpClient to take system properties into account, which it does not do by default

```
 CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createSystem();
```

or

```
 CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
     .useSystemProperties()
     .build();
```

Comment: I tried all those properties. It didn't work. I don't have access to the source code of the tool to force it to use system properties.

Comment: Settings all these properties has no effect if the client has not been explicitly instructed to take them into account (as shown above). If the application in question does not provide you with a way to customize HttpClient configuration you are out of luck

Answer (score 2):

A working example with Apache HttpClient 4.5.*

Note: It does not work unless you use `HttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties().build();`

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost" , "myhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort" , "myport");
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser" , "myuser");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword" , "mypassword");

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties().build();

try {

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");

CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

    try {
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
        for (Header header : response.getAllHeaders()) {
            System.out.println("header " + header.getName() + " - " + header.getValue());
        }

        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        System.out.println("responseString :" + responseString);

    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

Instead of using System.setProperty you can set the properties with

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost="myhost" -Dhttp.proxyPort="myport" -Dhttp.proxyUser=myuser -Dhttp.proxyPassword="mypassword"
```

**Important**: If you try to access a **HTTPS** service you have to change the properties to https
**It also does not work if you use https.* properties and you access a http URL**

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost" , "myhost");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort" , "myport");
System.setProperty("https.proxyUser" , "myuser");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword" , "mypassword");

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties().build();

try {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
```

API: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/

**Pure Java - without Apache HttpClient**

You can set the same https.proxyHost etc properties if you use the **java.net.HttpURLConnection** class

**Always respect using https.proxyHost etc for https://... connections and http.proxyHost etc for http://... connections!**

```
String uri = "https://www.google.com/";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uri).openConnection();

InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

String inputLine; int x = 0;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    x++; if (x > 4) { break;}
}
in.close();
response.close();
```