# AWS Java SDK behind a corporate proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

I want to test my AWS code locally so I have to set a proxy to a AWS client.

There is a proxy host (http://user@pass:my-corporate-proxy.com:8080) set in my environment via a variable `HTTPS_PROXY`.

I didn't find a way how to set the proxy as whole so I came up with this code:

```
AmazonSNS sns = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
    .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig(System.getenv("HTTPS_PROXY")))
    .withRegion(Regions.fromName(System.getenv("AWS_REGION")))
    .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
    .build();

ClientConfiguration clientConfig(String proxy) {
    ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
    if (proxy != null && !proxy.isEmpty()) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\w{3,5})://((\\w+):(\\w+)@)?(.+):(\\d{1,5})").matcher(proxy);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Proxy not valid: " + proxy);
        }
        configuration.setProxyHost(matcher.group(5));
        configuration.setProxyPort(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(6)));
        configuration.setProxyUsername(matcher.group(3));
        configuration.setProxyPassword(matcher.group(4));
    }
    return configuration;
}
```

The whole method `clientConfig` is only boilerplate code.

Is there any elegant way how to achieve this?

Comment: Honestly given your environment this sounds about as good as it's going to get.  I'm not sure what sending an empty `ClientConfiguration` in the event that the proxy is not set does as I've not used this but I'm assuming it is ignored in that case.

Comment: a method like `clientConfiguration.setProxy(String proxy)` would be much better...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell while using AWS SDK V1 (1.11.840), if you have environment variables such as `HTTP(S)_PROXY` or `http(s)_proxy` set at runtime, or properties like `http(s).proxyHost`, `proxyPort`, `proxyUser`, and `proxyPassword` passed to your application, you don't have to set any of that. It gets [automatically](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/pull/596/files) read into the newly created `ClientConfigiration`.

As, such you'd only want to set the `ProxyAuthenticationMethod`, if needed.

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfig(ProxyAuthenticationMethod authMethod) {
    ClientConfiguration conf = new ClientConfiguration();
    List<ProxyAuthenticationMethod> proxyAuthentication = new ArrayList<>(1);
    proxyAuthentication.add(authMethod);
    conf.setProxyAuthenticationMethods(proxyAuthentication);
    return conf;
}
```

`ProxyAuthenticationMethod` can be `ProxyAuthenticationMethod.BASIC` or `DIGEST` or `KERBEROS` or `NTLM` or `SPNEGO`

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm setting the parameters "http(s).proxyHost" (and others) work out of the box, you *need* however to specify a port, otherwise AWS SDK (1) will not pick it up.

```
java -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.company.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=myUsername -Dhttps.proxyPassword=myPassword <app>
```

Username & passsword are optional.

See for more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

and

[What Java properties to pass to a Java app to authenticate with a http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630330/what-java-properties-to-pass-to-a-java-app-to-authenticate-with-a-http-proxy)